# Should the avatar of an organization in social networks be its logo?

Tags: user-engagement, avatar, facebook, social-network, volunteers

I have been promoted to an admin position of a Facebook page of a volunteer organization. One thing that surprises me, is that none of the avatars of the page are the logo. I will show some of them here (they are only for illustration purpose, I'll try to keep the question not too local).

[image: Example Logs]

In the first picture, there is a group of core people making the shape of the country's name by their hands. The organization works for the country's benefit, so it's unsurprising that this picture gets so many likes (38 likes, a very high number of likes comparing to other posts). In the other two pictures, you can see the logo of the organization, but in different context. These two also get lots of likes.

**Q:** I wonder if this kind of avatar really help to promoting the page? I have worked with them for almost a year, and in my humble opinion, when they used those avatars, they didn't really think about looking professional. But do they really need that? They are all volunteers, and I think the fans like these photos because they show the hard work and their dedication to the sake of the community. The first picture may seem to be messy, but the people look happy, and the viewers may see it as fun. Although using all these avatars may not be as professional as using the organization's logo, I think it will get more interaction with the fans than a logo would.

In order to get more interactions, what should I use as the avatar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question is: Do others identify your organization through your logo? 
 Like if someone see your logo, do they say "Ahh, that's such-and-such organization" If so, I highly recommend you put your logo as your avatar. 
The pros of it:

-Your organization will be identifiable from others. 
-It will be recognizable for all when they see one of your volunteers (workers)
-It will definitely help boost promotion of the project


If you are still skeptical, look at similar organizations. Do they have a logo? Most corporations, business, etc. have logos as their avatar. It doesn't make them any more or less unprofessional. 
You can put the picture with all the volunteers as the cover image. It will still show your handwork. 

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply. You are right. After reading your answer I realize that the number of likes those pictures got is because of the nature of them, irrelevant if they are avatars or not. New people is hardly to click on the avatar. The only thing that attracts interactions is how they appear in people's news feed.